# ¿Cómo enmascarar la URL en Django?

Tags: python, django, url

¿En django es posible enmascarar la url con un label como en YouTube?

Por ejemplo, yo tengo un archivo guardado en la carpeta media. La URL para el archivo sería:

- http://127.0.0.1:8080/media/documento.pdf

Y lo que me gustaría mostrar sería algo como esto:

- http://127.0.0.1:8080/doc_123

Algo parecido

No es lo que busco exactamente, pero esto es lo que he logrado hacer hasta ahora:

En la BD creé un campo que toma un valor UUID

```
url_change = models.CharField(default=generate_uuid, editable=False, unique=True, max_length=40)
```

En la lista de reportes, agrego un link para redireccionar al usuario hacia una página para que visualice el documento:

```
<a href="{% url 'almacen:reporte_response' repo.url_change %}" target="_blank">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info">Ver</button>
            </a>
```

En el views.py creé una función que filtra los reportes de la BD hasta encontrar el que tiene un valor similar al seleccionado anteriormente y solo devuelva la primera respuesta del query. Esto último para no tener que hacer un for en la template.

```
def ReporteResponse(request, url_change):
     file = Reportes.objects.filter(url_change=url_change).first()
     context = {'file': file,}
     return render(request, '../templates/almacen/report_view.html', context)
```

En el Template, utilizo la librería de Firefox para renderizar pdf dentro de una página web [PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/)

Y simplemente después agrego un botón de descarga.

La url final queda de la siguiente forma:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/almacen/reporte/ver/9faa839e5b314bf6aa64854420ca691d
```

Si alguien sabe una forma más facil, me gustaría leerla y probarla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar un `slug` que es una forma de generar una URL valida.

Este se configura directamente desde los modelos, siendo la forma mas fácil para generar urls y si es una pagina web al mismo tiempo estarás aportando al SEO de la pagina.

Te dejo el link a la documentación oficial  --> [Documentación Oficial SlugField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#slugfield)